# Можно ли SVG вставить как икону в title

Tags: html, веб-программирование, svg

Господа, вопрос собственно в самом заголовке, у меня LOGO для сайта написан в svg. А можно ли svg использовать как икону для title тоже, что бы не переводить в другой формат. Сейчас у меня другая икона и код выглядит так:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="./img/icon/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

А надо так:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="./img/svg/icon.svg" type="image/x-icon" />
```

но так файл svg не видит

Comment: ну это же генератор как я понял?

Comment: пока никак, конвертируй svg в png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконки в формате `svg` [поддерживаются](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg) только в Firefox, Opera и Safari, поэтому лучше использовать иконки в формате `ico` или `png`.

Comment: opera, давно уже на движке chrome. opera не поддерживает, а вот на FF попробовал, точно работает...  благодарю за ответ

Comment: Тем не менее, в Opera `svg`-иконки работают. :) Можно проверить [здесь](http://dahlström.net/svg/favicon/favicon.html). У меня отображается иконка `svg` в версии 48.0.2685.39 на Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (x86_64; Unity).

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите поменять тип картинки в линке, но указываете тип для файла ico. Для svg же другой тип - `image/svg+xml`. В будущем, когда используете атрибуты type - указывайте корректные MIME типы

Comment: В FF и так работает, в Safari не пробовал, а в Chrome и Opera, не работает ни как

Comment: @Air Ну полноценно SVG в качестве иконки поддерживается пока только в Firefox. Хотя и Flex в свое время тоже только там поддерживался, а теперь 98% браузеров. Так что вы можете сконвертировать эту svg в ico или png, а в шапке прописать 2 линка - первый на простую иконку, а после на svg - в итоге те что не поддерживают - будут грузить простую иконку, а те что поддерживают - SVG. Но в любом случае, MIME типы нужно указывать корректные. Да, в одной ситуации оно может работать, но это "не по форме"

Comment: Да это понятно, что когда-нибудь что-то измениться, в программировании, особенно web всегда так, но два линка, мне кажется глупо, лучше я щас в PNG все сделаю, а потом если измениться ситуация , буду использовать svg